# Can I reference the target variable within a With statement?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, dereference

**When creating a `With` statement like**

```
With A
   .Method1OfA
   .Method2OfA
   .Method3OfA
End With
```

**is there a way to reference the currently "`With`"ed variable within the `With` statement block?**

Since I don´t know of any, I find myself writing stuff like this:

```
With A
   .Method1OfA
   GlobalFunction (A)
   .Method2OfA
   GlobalFunction (A)
   .Method3OfA
End With
```

i.e. I am dereferencing `A` more often than I´d like. If I could write something like

```
With A
   .Method1
   GlobalFunction (currentlyWithed)
   .Method2
   GlobalFunction (currentlyWithed)
   .Method2
End With
```

with `currentlyWithed` "automatically" referring to `A`, I could avoid that dereference, which I want to, because if `A` is a complex term (which it probably is, being the reason for the `With` statement in the first place), I´d avoid multiple evaluations of that term.

The workaround solution a la

```
Dim B: Set B=A
With B
   .Method1
   GlobalFunction (B)
   .Method2
   GlobalFunction (B)
   .Method2
End With
```

is acceptable, but creates a temporary variable (`B`) which survives the scope of the `With` statement, and referencing it later by accident might create problems if `A` has changed meanwhile (i.e. if it has been modified meanwhile and references a different instance).

So I would expect there is something like `currentlyWithed` in VB.NET or VBScript, but i fail to find anything like that in the documentation.

Comment: Is this VB.NET or VbScript? They are not the same thing

Comment: Do I understand you correctly give this example: `Dim S As DataSet` and then you would do `With S.Tables("T") : Dim t As DataTable = currentlyWithed  : End With`?

Comment: @Matt, I am thinking about this for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do your workaround but in its own method. Although it creates a temporary object, it will go out of scope at the end of the method (meaning you don't have to worry about object not being cleaned up):

```
Public Sub DoSomething(a As Object)
    Dim B: Set B=a
    With B
       .Method1
       GlobalFunction (B)
       .Method2
       GlobalFunction (B)
       .Method2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You might re-delete this comment, but I still think this answer is not an answer because it is contained in the question. Well OK you suggest to isolate the block into a function. To let the temp var go out of scope. OK. +1. Might accept that one later.